# How to Fix "not allowed to load local resource" [Wordpress]

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am using the img tag but the code is in a php block.

```
<img class='client_image' src='" . get_stylesheet_directory() . "/assets/images/" . $print->client_images . "' alt='clientimage" . $clientindex . "' width='200' height ='200' />";
```

I keep getting not allowed to load local resource and I do not know why. I am using a premade wordpress theme. All I get is the broken image icon. The path is correct as well as the name of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_stylesheet_directory()` will returns the path on your server, you need `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead:

```
<img class='client_image' src='" . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .    
"/assets/images/" . $print->client_images . "' alt='clientimage" . 
$clientindex . "' width='200' height ='200' />";
```

Comment: Wow, did not know there was a difference. Thank you.